# What are some weapons that allow you to block and attack at the same time in dark souls II?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I tried out the "Heide Spear" and although the damage seems to be weak, I noticed i am capable of simultaneously block and attack. The blocking is 100% uptime during all frames of my attack. So basically I can attack and block at 100% uptime on both, only problem is stamina. I wanted to ask what other weapons in dark souls 2 have this capability? before I got this weapon, it was my understanding that you can not block and attack at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Dark Souls 1 you could attack from behind shields with spears and rapiers this has been transferred to the second game...

The big change in Dark Souls 2 for weapons of this Nature is the Halberd you can use your Halberd as you would a spear from behind your shield this however changes the type of attack to thrust as apposed to slash so be aware of the enemies resistance to stabbing attacks. As for other Weapons that can be used from behind the shield there are Rapiers and all other types of spear and halberd with a point.

As for your Stamina you can find many ways of increasing the recovery speed such as The Cloranthy Ring and green blossom.

Comment: Might be this one if I understand you right. http://darksouls.wikia.com/wiki/Cloranthy_Ring